# How to close a MessageBox window by its handle with C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, messagebox

I have a multi-threaded application that may display a MessageBox for a user's interaction. The message box itself is displayed from a worker thread, after a user picks a context menu command from the app's system tray icon, so the user can technically continue using the app while the message box is displayed. This works great until a user issues "Exit" command, at which point I need to find a way to close any open message boxes.

I did my homework and I was able to obtain HWND handle for the main (dialog) window of the message box ([using this method](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10037/How-to-change-the-MessageBox-window-Add-controls-a).) I checked the HWND to be correct using Spy++, so HWND itself is not the issue. What happens is that when I do `PostMessage(hMsgBoxWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);` from another thread to the message box, it simply ignores this message and doesn't close.

Any idea how to close the message-box by its window handle?

Comment: I think this will be a lot easier to handle by displaying a dialog that looks like a message box, so you know what message to send it to get it to close.

Comment: That's odd because I swear I used the exact same technique somewhere before and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Yes it would, but it would also involve me re-writing alot of the code. I'll try to find the solution to this issue first...

Comment: I don't know why WM_CLOSE wouldn't work but you could also try posting it a WM_COMMAND message to simulate the clicking of one of the buttons (e.g. `PostMessage(hMsgBoxWnd, WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(IDCANCEL, BN_CLICKED), 0);`

Comment: @JonathanPotter: It seems like MessageBox API still uses main thread message pump even if I called it from a worker thread and that seems to be the reason why WM_CLOSE gets bogged down...

Comment: @user843732: `MessageBox()` uses the message queue of the thread that is calling it.  Internally, `MessageBox()` runs its own message loop since it is a modal dialog. `MessageBox()` simply does not respond to `WM_CLOSE` in some sitations: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/18be2271-d7ec-4fee-9960-e90a4cb91758

Answer (score 1):

`MessageBox()` simply does not process `WM_CLOSE` in all sitations:

[SendMessage/PostMessage WM_CLOSE to MessageBox window does not always work](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/18be2271-d7ec-4fee-9960-e90a4cb91758)

Answer (score 0):

You should use PostThreadMessage to post to the threads specific message queue

Comment: You might have a point, although PostThreadMessage wouldn't work in my case because that worker thread doesn't have a message pump...

Comment: @user843732, You could add in a quick `PeekMessage` loop as to not greatly interfere with the other components of that thread.

Comment: @chris: you see the issue is (like I posted above) that MessageBox evidently still uses  main thread to get its messages. The reason I know this is because when I specify NULL as its first argument my closing method starts to work. The problem here is that MessageBox then creates its own button on the taskbar that I don't want...

Comment: @user843732, I feel terrible for even saying this, but if that's the only problem, you can use `SetWindowLongPtr` to change the extended style of the message box to `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` right after you make it. That should work as a hackish last resort before it needs to be done.

Comment: Another option is to use SetWindowsHookEx and intercept the windows messagebox messages, or making an auto-closing message box. This article discusses how to customize the standard message box: http://www.catch22.net/tuts/custom-messagebox

Comment: @stamhaney: This is pretty much what I do. I liked to the article in my original post that explains it.

Comment: @chris: Thanks. I tried the `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` style on the MessageBox but after that dragging it created some weird visual effect. I guess, they never envisioned that style to be used with it, so I'll refrain from it as well. What I ended up doing is periodically pumping the main message pump by calling CWinThread::PumpMessage() from within my worker thread. I had to do it from within a critical section, but otherwise I can't seem to fix it... Full code is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dy7kd92(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @user843732, Weird, I guess that's to be expected with hackish solutions, but I'm not sure why it would matter if it's a tool window or not.

Comment: @chris: when I do `MessageBox(NULL, ...);` instead of `MessageBox(hMainAppWnd, ...);` the latter call uses main thread's message pump to process any messages sent to the messagebox even if the API itself is called from a worker thread. The former call does not. It evidently creates its own message pump. Tool window simply hides the button from the taskbar, but, as I said, it creates a weird visual effect...